# CSS changes on refresh

Tags: css, safari, refresh, stylesheet

The contacts page of this website is fully functional, but when you refresh the page the CSS property `display:inline;` for the navigation list becomes void. This problem only exists in Safari.

The same CSS stylesheet is used for two other pages and they are fine, so I'm very confused!

http://www.katieburchett.co.uk/Contacts.html

Comment: where is the website??

Comment: Is something else overriding that style rule for that element?  Is there JavaScript code that's changing the style information after the page loads?  We can't help you without any information.

Comment: @David sorry! Updated with the website!

Comment: @KieranVyas: I'm unable to reproduce the error.  The styling works fine in my browser.

Comment: @David even after refreshing the page a few times?

Comment: @David yep it seems this problem only persists in Safari!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your HTML markup is invalid.  As long as that's the case, I'd expect any behavior to be undefined and browser-specific.  You have this:

```
<ul>
    <a href="index.html">
        <li>Home</li>
    </a>
    <!-- and so on -->
</ul>
```

[According to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html), only `li` elements are permitted as immediate children of `ul` elements.  So the markup *should* be this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <!-- and so on -->
</ul>
```

After making that change, of course, you may need to adjust your CSS selectors/rules to account for the new markup.

Any time you're seeing strange markup/style behavior, *especially* when it's browser-specific, the *first* thing you should do is [validate your code](http://validator.w3.org).